# ES6 template literal with object

Tags: ecmascript-6, template-literals

I have a function which prints an template literal:

```
function func() {
  const obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  };
  console.log(`obj = ${obj}`);
}
```

It prints "obj = [object Object]".

If I want to log the content of the object(prints "obj = {a: 1, b: 2}"), how can I revise the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) it.

```js
function func() {
  const obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  };
  console.log(`obj = ${JSON.stringify(obj)}`);
}

func();
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. But I insist that it should be the default behavior to print the content of object without JSON.stringify.

Comment: @JimJin Well normal object support more than what JSON does, so that could create problems. You could always just `console.log('obj = ', obj)` since it accepts multiple parameters  and you would get a real log of the object (*which you can explore in the console*)

Comment: @JimJin Then use `const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, toString(){ return JSON.stringify(this); }};`. That's what `toString` is for - and the default behaviour of objects is to print `[object …]`.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I'm not only using console.log, but also using log4js to record these object parameters. Does log4js support multiple parameters?

Comment: @Bergi Thank you! Does node support this grammar? I don't use babel. And more, do I have to modify every object definition like this?